# SSN for a H4 child for tax credit for year 2018

Tags: taxes

I am on H1B and have one child on H4 who is born outside USA.

To avail the child tax credit worth $2000 for the tax year 2018, is my child eligible to apply for SSN? I do see an option on the SSN form for not-authorized-to-work, however not sure if there is any other ground on which application could be rejected.

She already has ITIN which we got few years back when we landed here and filed our first return.

Answer (score 3):

No, an H4 child is not authorized to work in the US, and thus, cannot generally get a Social Security Number. One is generally only eligible to get an SSN for the first time (i.e. if one doesn't have an SSN before) if one is authorized to work in the US.

SSNs for people who are not authorized to work are only granted in rare circumstances, which I don't think your child would qualify for. And even in the unlikely chance your child could get a non-work SSN, it would say "not valid for employment" on it, which would still not allow you to get the Child Tax Credit for your child starting in 2018 -- it requires that an SSN valid for employment to have been issued before the due date of the tax return.

Your child can only get the $500 credit for other dependents starting in 2018.

Comment: Makes sense. Even if issued, it won't be authorizing for work which I see as a requirement. #LegalImmigrantStillMoreTaxes :(